# Is $f:A\to A$ an identity map?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity element and $f:A\to A$ be an isomorphism, for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$, $f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)=\mathfrak p$, is $f$ an identity map?

Answer (score 4):

No necessarily, for example, let $A$ be a field and $f$ a nontrivial
field automorphism. For instance $A=\Bbb C$ and $f$ complex conjugation.